# recommend a PHP script to create XML sitemap? (crawl/scrape method)

Tags: php, xml, apache, sitemap

I'm happy to write my own but if there's a really nice PHP script out there that i can just run on a cron and exclude directories then i'd love to hear about it!

I'd prefer to use a scraper/crawler type script than write the XML from the database....

Comment: I would recommend (ab)using `wget` for this kind of thing, but you'll need to massage your result from that somewhat. Here a guy seems to use it: http://ardoino.com/15-google-php-wget-sitemap-generator/ Can't vouch for the PHP code, but you get the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators

As far as the database interaction, you can adapt one of the above.

Comment: yes this was the first place i looked, the page hasn't been updated for the best part of a decade though...   as for db, as i said i don't want a db solution

Comment: I've added my own php script on GitHub https://github.com/johnbe4/getSeoSitemap .
It crawls a whole site.
It checks all internal and external links saving the sitemap.xml and sitemap.xml.gz into your server.
There is no limit of URLs.
All you need is php 5.4, SQL database and access to cronotab of the server.